# Media Query Logic

Tags: android, iphone, css, responsive-design, media-queries

As a very simple approach to "responsive design", I have two version of CSS for a website I'm working on:

- a regular (non-mobile) version that should display on any devices
  with the screen wider than 700px;
- a streamlined mobile version, to be displayed on any device with the
  screen equal in width, or narrower than 700px.

I used `@media only screen and (max-device-width : 700px)` query to separate the two sets of CSS rules.

I also use this JavaScript snippet to assign viewport meta tag parameters based on the width of the screen:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var width = screen.width;
var height = screen.height; 
var meta = document.createElement("meta");
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

if (width >= 700) {
    meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "width=1000");
    head.appendChild(meta);
} else if (width <700) {
    meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1");
    head.appendChild(meta);
};

</script>
```

The script sets the width of the viewport to 1000px if the device has the screen width >= 700px, essentially making sure that the entire width of the non-mobile version of the website fits within the screen, and sets initial scale to 1 if the screen width is less than 700px.

Again, just to clarify, what I want to accomplish is this: when the screen width is > 700px, show regular (non-mobile) website; when the screen width is <= 700px, show streamlined (mobile) website.

The results surprised me:

- Samsung Galaxy S (480x800) - non-mobile version, landscape and
  portrait positions
- Samsung Galaxy S II (480x800) - non-mobile version, landscape and portrait positions
- Motorola Droid Razr (540x960) - non-mobile version, landscape and
  portrait positions
- Motorola Droid 4 (540x960) - non-mobile version, landscape and
  portrait positions
- Motorola Photon 4G (540x960) - non-mobile version,    landscape and
  portrait positions
- Motorola Atrix HD (720x1280) - mobile version (!), landscape and portrait
  positions (even though both screen dimensions are wider than would
  satisfy the mobile query!)
- Motorola Razr (540x960) - mobile version, landscape and portrait
  positions (even though its landscape position is wider than 700px)
- HTC Wildfire (240x320) - non-mobile version (!), landscape and
  portrait positions (even though it has the smallest screen
  dimensions, both way smaller than 700px!)
- Sony Xperia X10 (480x854) - mobile version, portrait and landscape
  positions (even though its landscape position is wider than 700px)
- LG Optimus 3D (480x800) - non-mobile version, portrait and
  landscape positions
- Amazon Kindle Fire 2 (600x1024) - mobile version, portrait and
  landscape positions (even though its wider dimension is way above
  700px)

From what I see, I conclude that mobile devices are a mess. Most devices seem to recognize the highest dimension as the max-width, but some (Amazon Kindle 2) appear to treat lower dimension as the "width" and higher as the "height". Some devices have screen dimensions below 700px but "pretend" to have higher ones.

It seems that I used faulty logic when I tried to use `max-device-width` of 700 as the defining factor for a media query.

**Question:** to create a media query that would cover as many devices as possible with the following rule: "if the current width of the screen is <= 700px, apply the mobile CSS" – what should be the proper additional conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you included the `viewport` meta tag?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

After seeing your `viewport` script I'm wondering if this is causing the issue

```
var width = screen.width;

if (width >= 700) {
    meta.setAttribute("name", "viewport");
    meta.setAttribute("content", "width=1000");
    head.appendChild(meta);
}
```

Wont the `width` variable be set to over 700 since at the time it queries the screen width, the device will be defaulting to scale the page?

Comment: Thank you, @Duncan. Yes, of course, I do use the viewport meta tag, in fact, I actually added a little JavaScript snippet to control what parameters are added to the viewport meta tag, depending on the screen width. I am adding this to the question.

Comment: I assume that you are adding the 2 stylesheets in the right order? If your mobile styles are added first they might be overwritten by the 'standard' ones. look at [media queries after base styles](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/AEt5S/1/) compared to [media queries before base styles](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/AEt5S/2/)

Comment: Interesting thought, @Duncan. Let me test this. (The styles are in the right order, of course, regular CSS first.

Comment: I'm back – and your most recent suggestion was a major step in the right direction, @Duncan. I set the width to device-width, and the site now shows consistently as mobile across the majority of mobile devices. One problem though: it now shows as mobile even on the devices whose width is actually higher than 700px. Any suggestions on how to handle that?

Comment: could you update the question with some specifics about the devices wtill causing issues and ideally the relevant code from the document `<head>` and the `@media` query itself?

Comment: Hang on, @Duncan, doing some more testing. It seems that what Ian suggested earlier about setting media query to max-width rather than max-device makes some of the devices wider than 700px behave as if their width were 700px or less. Which may not be all that bad, with a couple of exceptions...

Comment: Update: the problem is solved, the issue was the combination of max-device-width (that counted actual physical dimensions of the screen size rather than "squashed" pixel size), and the 1000px setting in the js snippet. Works perfect now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As Duncan mentions, add the `viewport` tag.

Ideally set it to something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And then adjust your media query to use `max-width` rather than `max-device-width`.

I'd be interested to see your test results after making those changes.

Comment: Yep, @Ian, I have viewport meta handled, even though not in a very stanadard way. Please take a look at the edited question.

Comment: Update: changing max-device-width to max-width didn't have any effect  at all, @Ian, on any of the devices.